# Run sosex in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windbg, sos

I very like use [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) Debugging Extension for my .NET projects from Visual Studio. There is also [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/default.aspx) Debugging Extension with additional commands, but I can use SOSEX only from WinDbg. Is there some way to use SOSEX from Visual Studio? I tried run it from Immediate Window:

```
.load D:\sosex\sosex.dll
Error during command: IDebugClient asked for unimplemented interface
Error during command: extension initialization failed
```

Comment: I'm 95% sure that's never going to work, Windbg required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WinDbg integration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariohewardt/archive/2012/06/05/visual-studio-2012-and-windbg-integration.aspx) feature of Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Hmm, surely you can expand on this answer a bit and mention the benefits of unmanaged debugging another process in the Immediate window over unmanaged debugging in Windbg?

Comment: @HansPassant, I like work in VisualStudio without set of additional applications. It's single benefit for me.

Answer (score 5):

SOSEX won't work with VS.  I've not had enough time or demand to make it work there.  Sorry about that.